# 401 Unauthorized using OmniAuth-Twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, omniauth, twitter-oauth

I am getting a `401 Unauthorized` when trying to implement the `OmniAuth-Twitter` gem into my rails app in `Development` I have read several posts saying the server times are mismatched.

The error comes when calling `http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter`

I have a callback url.
I have the api keys correct.
So I assume the timestamp is the issue.

How exactly can I go about comparing twitter's server time to my local machine's time?

How do I go about adjusting my local machine's time?

Comment: You have to look at your call back url in twitter api where you mention you call back url it should be start with **http:// 127.0.0.1/* **

Comment: @dark-wish it does...

Comment: are you using consumer_key and consumer_secret or access tokens ?

Comment: can post the rake:routes output here ?

Comment: @ajet yes I am using consumer keys. I really just need the timestamp info...

Comment: hi @Deekor, could you solve this problem?, I'm still struggling with this :/

Comment: hi, not notice that was your own answer, i was trying this a month ago, but not luck, so i continued with other stuffs in my project, when i post this i try with my old branch and everything works... so i'm guessing that was a twitter issue that time, that's why i think you could have another extra solution, thanks for reply!, regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was following this [railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth-revised). In it he states to set the keys like:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
   provider :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_KEY'], ENV['TWITTER_SECRET']
end
```

But the gem documentations states:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
   provider :twitter, "CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET"
end
```

Removing the `ENV[]` solved the issue.

Comment: The ENV[] calls are there because you shouldn't put your authentication keys and especially secrets directly into code, where it could some day end up in a public GitHub repository or otherwise exposed to the wrong people. 

You should instead put these values into config/environment variables in your OS and on your host. ENV[] fetches those values from the environment.